# How to autofill webform with node field data

Tags: 8, entities, webforms

I have a content type, `applicant` with a `name`, and `birthday` field. I also have a entity reference to a webform, which has a `name` and `birthday` fields, as well as others. I want to allow users to create the `applicant` content type, then click the link to webform, and autofill the appropriate fields on the webform.

I've been trying to use the `FormStateInterface::setValue` method. Here' where I am so far:

```
function mymodule_webform_element_alter(array &$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
  kint($element); // this outputs '#webform_key' => string(4) "name"

  $form_state->setValue('name', 'bob'); // Here I'm just trying to statically set the field.
}
```

This method doesn't actually autofill, and it also doesn't actually set the value. This is a demo-project, so we don't have specs yet, so I'm actually fine with either auto-filling, or setting the value, probably both.

The main thing I'm trying to do here is to link one node entity to a webform submission.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily assume `#webform_key` and the key of the element in the form array are related (maybe you know better from debugging?). `hook_form_alter` might be a better place to approach this either way

Comment: You shouldn't need to do such low level stuff. You can set default values when you render a webform or if the webform is embedded in a node you can use node tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x), you can set the default value by php code

**For Example**

```
function HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'YOUR_FROM_ID'){
    $form['submitted']['FIELDNAME']['#default_value'] = date("Y-m-d h:i a", time());
  }
}
```

Comment: slight correction: `$form['elements']['FIELDNAME']['#default_value'] = 'f<insertfieldvalue>';`

Comment: It was just an example to give a hint and glad it works for you.